# disappoint about google datastore insert performance

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I just did a small test, google datastore insert performance is only 10 rows per second. How can I use this for big high volumn i/o project. or Anyone know any trick that can make it faster. At least 50 rows per second insert.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your test code

Comment: How are you measuring the performance? You should be able to achieve much better results. Using at least: "multiple inserts in one UPSERT" and "multiple thread / process"